# Hidden form field but to still show required validation if no set value

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation

I have some form fields that are populated with javascript based on how the user interacts with the webpage.

```
<input type="hidden" class="evaluation_answer" required name="evaluation_1"/>
<div class="options">
    <div class="option">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

The value for this field gets populated with some javascript.

```
var stars = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-star-o");
for(var i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
    stars[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        console.log("empty star clicked...");

        var sib = this.parentNode.parentNode;
        sib = sib.getElementsByTagName("i");
        console.log(sib);
        for(var u = 0; u < sib.length; u++) {
            sib[u].classList.remove("fa-star");
            sib[u].classList.add("fa-star-o");
            sib[u].style.color = "#444";
        }

        this.classList.remove("fa-star-o");
        this.classList.add("fa-star");

        for(var u = 0; u < sib.length; u++) {
            if(sib[u].classList.contains("fa-star")) {
                var index = u;
                break;
            }
        }

        var hidden_input = this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        hidden_input = hidden_input.getElementsByClassName("evaluation_answer");
        hidden_input[0].value = index + 1;
```

This gives this hidden input field a value depending on the index of whatever it was they clicked on the page (not important), however, should they have not clicked anything in and still wish to submit the form, this field will have no value set. I've tried adding the required tag to this hidden input field, however the validation popup/alert (chrome) doesn't show.

Is there any way to show these required validation messages?

tl;dr: In Chrome, any required fields that have not been given a value will alert the user that that field is required upon submission, if you set the field to hidden, it doesn't show this validation. Any fix?/workaround? I know this is working as intended, however I'd prefer a validation message.

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with my question @andrew

Comment: You say you want to require a hidden form field. It makes sense to me this has no effect since a hidden field can't be manipulated by the user. So use JavaScript to write a require script.

Comment: I have a rating system where a hidden field is populated based on the index of the star clicked for that row, so in effect they are influencing the value of that field @bloodyKnucles